# How to save audios with custom name in Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm trying make bot that saves audio and work with it. And I want to save audios as `audio.mp3`

I tried to do it this way:

```
with open('audio.mp3','w') as a:
            a.write(await message.audio.download())
```

But it didn't work. It saves it that way:

```
music
----file_1.mp3
```

How can I save audios with custom name?

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `urllib` library

```py
import urllib.request

url = message.audio.url
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "audio.mp3")
```

this will download the audio file from the `url` and save it to the current working directory with the name "audio.mp3".

Comment: If I use urllib will all the limit disappear?

Comment: Using urllib does not change or remove any limitations or restrictions that may exist on the file or on the server hosting the file.